# Function error, passing as array

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am calling a function from a sub but it just doesn't work. Ive spent so much time trying to find out why but i just don't see it. I get compile error: Expected array.

Here is the whole code. I commented over the problematic line

Sub innout()

```
Dim numclosed As Long, numnew As Long
Dim lblvar As Variant
Dim tblcr As Range
Dim lrcr As Long
Dim finishdates As Range
Dim lastupdate As Long, msg As Long



Sheets("combined_report").Select

    lrcr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    tblcr = Range("A6:AB" & lrcr)
    lastupdate = Range("F2").Value


    finishdates = Range("T6:T" & lrcr)

    For Each cell In finishdates

        If cell.Value >= lastupdate And cell.Value < Date Then

            If cell.Offset(0, -5).Value = "Completed" Then

                    numclosed = numclosed + 1

            End If

        End If

    Next

Sheets("Tasks_to_do").Select

    Dim lrttd As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim numttd As Long
    Dim svrange As Range
    Dim resp As String, svname As String

    lrttd = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    numnttd = lrttd - 1

    Set svrange = Range("K2:K" & lrttd)

    For Each cell In svrange
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            numnew = numnew + 1
            resp = cell.Offset(0, -6).Value
'ERROR ON THIS LINE                
            cell.Value = svname(resp)
        End If
    Next

    msg = MsgBox("*************************" & Chr(13) & "Items closed yesterday: " & numclosed & Chr(13) & "New items as of now: " & numnew, vbOKOnly, "Mproduct item activity")
```

End Sub

Function svname(resp As String) As String

```
Dim respdb As Range
lrs As Long

Sheets("Supervisors").Select
    lrs = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    respdb = Range("A2:A" & lrs)
     For Each cell In respdb
        If cell.Value = resp Then
            svname = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
```

End Function

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `svname` as a local variable in addition to a function. Remove the second declaration and it should work:

```
Dim resp As String', svname As String <- error caused by this bit
```